# Annotate in one model Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

See my model

https://github.com/rg3915/morris/blob/master/myproject/core/models.py

How to return percent 'uf' of total?

Example:

'uf','quant'

'AM',8

'SP',9

'RJ',4

I try

```
p=Person.objects.values('uf').annotate(quant=Count('uf', distinct=True)).values_list('uf','quant')
print(p.query)
```

but return

```
SELECT "core_person"."uf", COUNT(DISTINCT "core_person"."uf") AS "quant" FROM "core_person" GROUP BY "core_person"."uf", "core_person"."first_name" ORDER BY "core_person"."first_name" ASC
```

and i need

```
SELECT "core_person"."uf", COUNT(DISTINCT "core_person"."uf") AS "quant" FROM "core_person" GROUP BY "core_person"."uf" ORDER BY "core_person"."uf" ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, I'm going to assume that you are looking to retrieve a list of states and the total number of people that belong to that state.

You were pretty close in your attempt, however you were lacking an [`order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) that would have let you choose the order field.

As such your query should look like this:

```
Person.objects.values('uf').annotate(quant=Count('uf')).order_by('uf').values_list('uf','quant')
```

I hope you'll notice that I have also removed the `distinct=True` argument from the `Count` function, as we want to be able to group all of the similar results.

Comment: I came very close to it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, but return

[('AC', 10), ('AL', 9), ('AM', 8), ('AP', 8), ('BA', 11),...

How to return

[(uf:'AC', quant:10), (uf:'AL', quant:9), (uf:'AM', quant:8), (uf:'AP', quant:8), (uf:'BA', quant:11),...

Comment: Resolved: Person.objects.values('uf').annotate(quant=Count('uf')).order_by('uf').values('uf', 'quant')